# AS3 rotating a button, but not HIT

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am trying to rotate a button in my program that has a large hit box. Obviously, when I do this, the hit box is also rotated and is now in the wrong place. Is it possible to get this hit box to remain static, or to just keep it there?

```
    var turnButton:Tween=new Tween
      (sections.lower, 'rotation', Strong.easeOut, 0, 180, 3, true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really, but there are workarounds. You can set the hit area as a circle (which is rotation invariant) and set it so the pivot of the rotation is the center of the circle. If you could provide me with an image of what's going on I could be of more help though.